# How to serve React built files to Spring Boot application

Tags: java, reactjs, spring, spring-boot, webpack

I have a Spring Boot application that has multiple APIs and a standart React application that was created using the ***create-react-app*** command. What I want to do is to build the React app using

> npm run build

and serve the built files from the Spring Boot application.

Here is my project structure:

[image]

Right now, during development I set a proxy to the frontend/package.json in order to send all requests to the backend server but need the same behaviour in production. How do I achieve that?

package.json:

```
"proxy": "http://localhost:8082/gui",
```

I also need everything packaged together in my war so in my pom.xml I use a couple of plugins to build the React app and copy the built files to the Spring Boot target folder:

```
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>com.github.eirslett</groupId>
                <artifactId>frontend-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>1.6</version>
                <configuration>
                    <workingDirectory>frontend</workingDirectory>
                    <installDirectory>target</installDirectory>
                </configuration>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>install node and npm</id>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>install-node-and-npm</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <nodeVersion>v12.13.1</nodeVersion>
                            <npmVersion>6.12.1</npmVersion>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                    <execution>
                        <id>npm install</id>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>npm</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <arguments>install</arguments>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                    <execution>
                        <id>npm run build</id>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>npm</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <arguments>run build</arguments>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-antrun-plugin</artifactId>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <phase>generate-resources</phase>
                        <configuration>
                            <target>
                                <copy todir="${project.build.directory}/classes/public">
                                    <fileset dir="${project.basedir}/frontend/build" />
                                </copy>
                            </target>
                        </configuration>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>run</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
```

An important information is that the Spring Boot app has a custom context path:

```
server.servlet.context-path=/gui
```

so the homepage should be served from localhost:8080/gui.
I need to know how to serve the frontend from my Spring Boot server. Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0):

I'm doing the same thing.

First of all, sure you have spring mvc and templating dependencies, eg:

```
implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web:3.2.3'
implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf:3.2.3'
```

Next, override the thymeleaf prefix property to point at your UI, eg, if you place your built React application in `/static/` then you would put:

```
spring.thymeleaf.prefix=${UI_LOCATION:file:///static/}
```

Alternatively, you can put your built React application into the default templating location for thymeleaf, being (at time of writing):

```
spring.thymeleaf.prefix=classpath:/templates/
```

So you'd be putting the contents of your build directory in `./src/main/resources/templates/`

At this point, when developing, you're probably hitting your UI server to run the UI, which points at the backend API spring boot app.

If you wanted to hit the spring boot app and get the UI in development you'd need to do the following:

```
spring.thymeleaf.prefix=file:///absolute/path/to/your-ui/
spring.thymeleaf.cache=false
spring.web.resources.static-locations=file:///absolute/path/to/your-ui/
```

This ensures that thymleaf serves up your in-development React application, and doesn't cache anything so you can make live changes, and that any relative or absolute paths referenced in your javascript are handled correctly by spring web/mvc.